# Is declaring a reference and passing it in the same as just passing by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

Say you have a function like this:

```
void func(int & arg) {
    std::cout << arg << std::endl;
}
```

Is doing something like:

```
int x = 10;
int & y = x;

func(y);
```

the same as:

```
int x = 10;

func(x)
```

Does `arg` become a `int && arg` or does it stay a `int & arg` when you pass in a pre-declared reference like the first case?

Comment: you can not distinguish `y` and `x` in any way except for exactly `decltype(x)` vs `decltype(y)`

Comment: There's no such thing as a reference to a reference. `int&& arg` has a different meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they're same. As [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference),

> Declares a named variable as a reference, that is, an alias to an already-existing object or function.

You can consider `y` as an alias of `x`, passing `y` to the function `func` has the same effect as passing `x` directly.